# What can be the repercussion for Philosophy of Science the discard of Math in Theoretical Physics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

The peer-reviewed journal Physics Essays published two days ago a paper where it is proven that a wrong math procedure is used in nuclear physics, for the calculation of the magnetic moments for excited even-even 2+ nuclei.

The paper also shows evidences that some excited even-even 2+ nuclei have null magnetic moment. But this is impossible by considering the foundations of the Nuclear Physics, and thereby there is no way to calculate a null magnetic moment for those excited nuclei, from any current nuclear model.

The repercussion of this misfire is the total collapse of Nuclear Physics, because a null magnetic moment of some excited even-even 2+ nuclei implies that are wrong some of the fundamental pillars on which the theory was developed, and therefore they must be rejected and replaced by new ones, from which a new nuclear model can be able to explain the null magnetic moment for those nuclei.

In order to save the Nuclear Physics from the total collapse, the nuclear theorists are using a wrong math procedure for the calculation of the magnetic moment of some excited even-even nuclei 2+, as did the authors of the paper "Magnetism of an Excited Self-Conjugate Nucleus: Precise Measurement of the g Factor of the 2+ State in 24Mg", published in 2015:

https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.062501

The abstract of the paper published by Physics Essays two days ago is shown ahead.

**Abstract:** *Data extracted from the Atomic Data and Nuclear Data Tables [S. Raman et al., At. Data Nucl. Data Tables 78, 1 (2001)] are used for the calculation of magnetic moments of atomic nuclei. However, in October 2018, the author discovered that when nuclear theorists use Raman’s table, an incorrect math procedure is applied when calculating the magnetic moments for exotic excited even Z = N nuclei. Obviously, it is mandatory for nuclear theorists to ascertain the repercussions of such an error in nuclear physics.*
https://physicsessays.org/browse-journal-2/product/1734-6-wladimir-guglinski-wrong-math-procedure-used-in-nuclear-physics-for-the-calculation-of-magnetic-moments-of-excited-z5n-even-even-nuclei.html

Along the last 10 years the nuclear theorists have rejected the results of some experiments. Let us see two examples:

1- In 2012 the journal Nature published the paper "How atomic nuclei cluster", which detected by experiments that Z=N even-even nuclei have spherical shape. In spite of this is impossible from the Foundations of the Nuclear Physics, the nuclear theorists do not confess that some principles of the theory are wrong. https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.1244

2- In 2009 an experiment measured as being 7 fm the orbit radius of Be11, and this is impossible from the foundations of Nuclear Physics, because the maximum range of interaction by strong nuclear force is 3 fm. Therefore a halo neutron with 7 fm is impossible. http://www.uni-mainz.de/eng/13031.php

But now the nuclear theorists are rejecting the own mathematics, in their desperate attempt of trying to save the pillars of Nuclear Physics, which are being demolished by experiments along the last 10 years.

Among the tasks of theoretical and experimental physics is the discovery of the laws that rule the working of the universe where we live. And the math is a fundamental tool from which we can test a theory, so that to verify if it is agree with the laws that rule the working of the universe.

**Then the question is:**

If the nuclear theorists discard the math in the process of verifying the foundations of the theory, are we able to get a thrustwhorty understanding on how the universe works? 
Is the rejection of the math compatible with the Philosophy of Science?

Comment: "Is the rejection of the math compatible with the Philosophy of Science?" What does it mean ? An incorrect result predicted by a theory may need a new theory. Maybe a new theory may need a "new math" meaning some mathematical theory not yed used in physics (think at tensor calculus for rwltivity and probability th with QM).

Comment: Maybe the recent published paper is simply wrong...

Comment: No, Mauro Allengranza, you are saying it because you dont  know what is the error in the math procedure. Physics Essays is a peer-reviewed journal. If had an error, the reviewer would had point it.  There is 100% of certainty that the procedure is wrong, and there is no way to correct it.

Comment: "An incorrect result predicted by a theory may need a new theory." Of course, Mauro. This is just what the author says in his paper. There is need to replace some foundations of nuclear physics by new ones.

Comment: The author discovered the error because he submitted a previous paper to the European Physical Journal, and the Editor-in-Chief Maria Borge rejected his paper, by citing a paper published by Phys Rev Let, in 2015.  The author read that paper, and discovered the error. Then he wrote a new paper, showing the error, but Maria Borge decided do not publish the new paper, because she is afraid of the repercutions for nuclear physics.  She is trying to stop the advancement of nuclear physics.

Comment: Maria Borge supposed that the paper published by Phys Rev Let in 2015 would be the proof that was wrong the first paper submitted to European Physical Journal, in 2018. But she could never imagine that the author would find that error in the wrong math procedure used in the paper published in Phys Rev Let. So, her argument, used for the rejection of the first paper submitted to EPJ in 2018, was proven wrong in the second paper submitted to EPJ in 2019.

Comment: Maria Borge rejected the first author's paper with a SCIENTIFIC argument. She showed a paper demolishing the author's argument in his first paper. But she DID NOT use a scientific argument for the rejection of the second paper.  In her Report she said that the paper was not suitable for publication in European Physical Journal.  In other words:  according to Maria Borge, a paper that demonstrates a wrong math procedure used in nuclear physics is not suitable for publication in the EPJ.

Comment: Not too sure what the question is. This all seems to be quite normal science going on: better experiments leads to better theories, leads to more accurate prediction leads to better experiments... Philosophy-of-Science is unlikely to suffer any repercussions. Maybe the "error" seems glaring, but as long as some useful predictions are made the model will be kept as a working theory until a better model is made.

Comment: christo, you are ENTIRELY WRONG. Do you mean to say that Philosophy-of-Science was unlikely to suffer any repercussions after 1919, when Einstein's relativity theory was confirmed by the solar eclipse??? The FOUNDATIONS of Physics were changed, and do you mean to say that there was not any repercussion in the Philosophy-of-Science?????

Comment: Besides, the question is not about either the "error" to be glaring or not. You did not understand the problem. According to the current Nuclear Physics, it is IMPOSSIBLE the existence of null magnetic moment for excited even-even nuclei with spin 2+. This means that the FOUNDATIONS of Nuclear Physics ARE WRONG. And therefore it is IMPOSSIBLE to get a better nuclear model, because it is IMPOSSIBLE to get it from the current WRONG FOUNDATIONS of Nuclear Physics.

Comment: In order to explain why excited even-even nuclei with spin 2+ have null magnetic moment, there is need a new nuclear model developed from NEW FOUNDATIONS, different of that addopted in the current Nuclear Physics.  There is need a New Nuclear Physics, totally different of the current theory.  Do you think, dear christo, that a NEW Nuclear Physics, based on NEW FOUNDATIONS, will not have repercussions in the Philosophy-of-Science ?????

Comment: christo, your argument is like to say: "Maybe the 'error' discovered by Einstein, and confirmed by the solar eclipse, seems glaring, but as long as some useful predictions are made with the Classical Physics, it will be kept as a working theory, until a better model is made"

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with philosophy, or even the philosophy of science.

If you look at the book by Einstein and Infeld, *The Evolution of Physics*, they point out carefully that it’s quite feasible to discuss the tundamental ideas of physics (and of mathematics) in prose as they are few in number.

It’s a mistake, that many people make, that mathematics and physics ought to be discussed in mathematical terms. Generally, I find, thenprose of such people is usually a massive exercise in pedantry, obscurity and opacity, almost as though they were trying deliberately to hide something.

Comment: Mozibur, you are an expert in pedantry, obscurity and opacity, that's why you understand very well this subject.

That nuclear theorists try to hide from people the total collapse of nuclear physics, it is perfectly understandable.

But the reason why phylosophers may try to hide the reality to the public, it is a mistery. 
The philosopher had to be an impartial defender of the scientific truth.  But he is not.
The philospher is actually a slave of the physicists.

Comment: I am sure that this topic was put in hold due to the pressure of nuclear physicists. They have a desperate hope that they can hide from the public that new experiments are demolishing the fundamental pillars of nuclear physics.
But the History of Physics tell us that this task is imposible.
Soon or later the nuclear physicits will recognize that nuclear physics was developed from wrong foundations. And this will repercute in the Philosophy-of-Science.

Comment: Karl Popper is writhing in his grave

Comment: @JaphaNakhão: I don't agree with everyhting that Karl Popper wrote but he wrote with a great more clarity than you have.